# Optimize GEOSGeometry's spatial operations by avoiding thread-safety checks

Tags: python, algorithm, geodjango, topology, optimization

A ranking algorithm I'm developing for a Django webapp requires performing spatial operations (within, intersections, sym_difference, etc.) using a query against large number of geometry objects.

Presently, the algorithm is very time-consuming, and the profiler reveals that the bottleneck is `django.contrib.gis.geos.prototypes.threadsafe.__call__`, which are called by virtually every methods in `GEOSGeometry`. From what I understand, `threadsafe.py` is a wrapper to the underlying GEOS's threadsafe API.

In this case the threadsafe-checking presents huge overhead to the computation time. Also my computation is strictly single threaded. From these reasons, I wonder is it possible to bypass or avoid the thread-safety checking performing by Django's GEOS API?

Comment: try contacting the people in ticket [#10923](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10923)

Answer (score 4):

If you have one target geometry with a batch of many test geometries, try using a [prepared geometry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#prepared-geometries). See [this page](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/PreparedGeometry) for a good description of a prepared geometry.

Comment: +1 "Prepared geometry" is a *crucial* concept for efficient GIS analysis; it's nice to see it getting implemented somewhere!

Comment: I use `PreparedGeometry` for spatial predicate methods in my algorithm as well. The performance bottleneck, however, are mainly from topological methods (e.g. intersection, sym_difference), in which `PreparedGeometry` does not support. The algorithm needs these topological methods to find area of intersection, for instance.